# How do I debug an uninformative error message in apache/php?

Tags: php, apache, debugging, apache2

> **Warning**:  Directive
>   'register_long_arrays' is deprecated
>   in PHP 5.3 and greater in
>   **Unknown** on line **0**

Is the error message, as far as I can see I don't have it in my code/.htaccess file

Comment: That looks like a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 3):

Check your php.ini file -- [`register_long_arrays`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-long-arrays) is an ini directive.